# Matching multiple unicode characters in Golang Regexp

Tags: regex, go, unicode

As a simplified example, I want to get `^⬛+$` matched against `⬛⬛⬛` to yield a find match of `⬛⬛⬛`.

```
    r := regexp.MustCompile("^⬛+$")
    matches := r.FindString("⬛️⬛️⬛️")
    fmt.Println(matches)
```

But it doesn't match successfully even though this would work with regular ASCII characters.

I'm guessing there's something I don't know about Unicode matching, but I haven't found any decent explanation in documentation yet.

Can someone explain the problem?

[Go Play](https://go.dev/play/p/eKeSgrnf4lm)

Comment: There's another codepoint between the block ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression matches a string containing one or more ⬛ (black square box).

The subject string is three pairs of black square box and variation selector-16.  The variation selectors are invisible (on my terminal) and prevent a match.

Fix by removing the variation selectors from the subject string or adding the variation selector to the pattern.

Here's the first fix: https://go.dev/play/p/oKIVnkC7TZ1

Comment: Thank you. I should've checked the string properly for invisible characters. Also TIL variation selectors!

Answer (score 4):

You need to account for all chars in the string. If you [analyze the string](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%E2%AC%9B%EF%B8%8F%E2%AC%9B%EF%B8%8F%E2%AC%9B%EF%B8%8F) you will see it contains:

[image]

So you need a regex that will match a string containing one or more combinations of `\x{2B1B}` and `\x{FE0F}` chars till end of string.

So you need to use

```
^(?:\x{2B1B}\x{FE0F})+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/21Qa37/1).

Note you can use `\p{M}` to match any diacritic mark:

```
^(?:\x{2B1B}\p{M})+$
```

See the [Go demo](https://go.dev/play/p/sMgj_8Lf1LN):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`^(?:\x{2B1B}\x{FE0F})+$`)
    matches := r.FindString("⬛️⬛️⬛️")
    fmt.Println(matches)
}
```